# MoP: vendor with 372 gear

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My monk just hit lvl 85 and I'm now doing MoP quests. Since I re-rolled to a new toon, I don't have my full heroic t13 gear and leveling is a bit of a pain with my monk's current gear. Rumor is, there's a vendor around these lands that sell ilvl 372 gear. Any insight as to where they are located and how I can get to them?

Comment: What is a toon?  Do you mean char?  I think you mean char.  Yea, you mean char.

Comment: I hope you are being sarcastic @OrigamiRobot

Comment: @JamesJiao No, people who say toon are horrible people.

Comment: more information about toon: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77192/what-is-the-source-for-calling-your-characters-toons

Comment: If you're newly leveled to MoP, consider these tradeskill created items as well: (green 384, blue 415)
Windwool (cloth) , Misthide (leather), Stormscale (mail), Ghost-Forged (plate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of them, I found this nice quote with some good info.
http://www.wowhead.com/npc=62737#comments:id=1723350

> This is one of the new gear vendors that are spread all across
>   Pandaria that sell complete sets of green gear. Great to start an
>   off-spec, or fill in that one missing slot in your main set. Here's a
>   list of all the vendors I've seen or heard of so far; if anyone else
>   finds more of these, let me know and I'll add them to the list.
>
> - All vendors have gear for all specs + slots
> - Though they only sell 1 ring/trinket these are NOT UNIQUE, so you can simply wear two at once!
> - All the i372 gear vendors have the same items.

```
iLvl/Min Lvl    Vendor              Zone - Location                             Notes
372/85          Rivett Clutchpop    The Jade Forest - Grookin Hill              Horde Only, requires completion of quests to appear
372/85          Silkweaver Rui      The Jade Forest - Pearlfin Village          Alliance Only, Pearlfin Jinyu discount
372/85          Singegruff          The Jade Forest - Dawn's Blossom            
372/85          Jambeezi            Valley of the Four Winds - Halfhill Village Trader  Walks around a bit
372/85          Claretta            Valley of the Four Winds - Pang's Stead 
393/87          The Metal Paw       Kun-Lai Summit - Binan Village      
393/87          Alin the Finder     Townlong Steppes - Longying Outpost         Shado-Pan Faction Discount
408/88          Supplier Xin        Townlong Steppes - Longying Outpost         Shado-Pan Faction Discount
```

Table modified to fit better.