# Toon VS Character VS Sprite

Tags: world-of-warcraft, terminology

I am hoping this is not a dumb question, but I have looked around and not knowing this is really bugging me.

I have heard many people talk about a "Toon" or a "Character", and a few times of a "Sprite", to refer to their fictional characters they play in the game.

I want to know if one of these are more correct than the other?

I have heard more people and websites refer to them as Characters, rather than a 'toon', but what is the difference, if any?

Comment: Just a way of speech. Just like I always greet with 'Heya', and other people with 'Hey' or 'yow' or 'hi' or not at all. Of course toon is shorter and therefor faster to write, but they mean exactly the same thing. I'm not sure about 'Sprite', never heard that one to be used in a MMORPG, but I suppose it is the same thing.

Comment: That makes sense, although you could abbreviate Character as 'char', which is then again equally as fast, if not faster.. But I get the preference side of it.

Comment: this is a result of habits developing over different MMOs coming together in one game.

Comment: for instance, city of heroes primarily used toon as a way of calling rolled characters.  Sprite may be final fantasy 11/14?(I've never played it so I wouldn't know).

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77192/what-is-the-source-for-calling-your-characters-toons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EU players refer to Character. The minimum call it "Toon" Mostly those who learn't the WoW terms from US Streamers. The Majority of the US players call it "Toon", with the minimum calling it "Character". And "Sprite" is a viable term too. Sprite is used the least from my 6 years of playing WoW. I barely ever heard it.Sprite is a therm more used in Nintendo games. like Pokemon or any games that are of that kind. In MMO's it's better to stick to Toon and Character.

But none the less there is really no difference between them. As a EU player myself I always say Character. Both are right. Use whichever you like more :)